# Exposing user details stored in Oracle DB to an LDAP server

Tags: oracle, ldap, openldap

We currently have a very large, custom built user database (Oracle DB) that we'd like to expose using standard technologies, specifically LDAP, to allow application that we don't manage to authenticate users against our details.

I've currently been looking at using openldap with a sql backend but have been unable to get it working with Oracle as of yet. I am currently trying to figure out if it is a problem with the ODBC settings (any odbc.ini or odbcinst.ini examples would be appreciated) or something else.
It has successfully connected to MySQL (using this tutorial http://www.wingfoss.com/content/how-to-install-openldap-with-mysql-on-debian6) but have been unable to get it working with a dynamic view instead of a table.

Has anyone had any experience in dealing with such a problem? Is LDAP the way to go or is there a more suitable technology I could make use of?

Comment: Have you had any luck with this ? I am interested in similar solution.

Comment: Best solution I came across was http://ldapjs.org/ but I have since abandoned the effort to find a solution.